# Differences between seaborn histogram, countplot and distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn, data-analysis

I think they all look the same but there must be some difference.

They all take a single column as input, and the y-axis has the count for all plots.

Answer (score 42):

Those plotting functions `pyplot.hist`, `seaborn.countplot` and `seaborn.displot` are all helper tools to plot the frequency of a single variable. Depending on the nature of this variable they might be more or less suitable for visualization.

#### Continuous variable

A continuous variable `x` may be histrogrammed to show the frequency distribution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)*100
hist, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(0,101,10))
plt.bar(edges[:-1], hist, align="edge", ec="k", width=np.diff(edges))

plt.show()
```

[image]

The same can be achieved using `pyplot.hist` or `seaborn.distplot`,

```
plt.hist(x, bins=np.arange(0,101,10), ec="k")
```

or

```
sns.distplot(x, bins=np.arange(0,101,10), kde=False, hist_kws=dict(ec="k"))
```

`distplot`<sup>1.</sup> wraps `pyplot.hist`, but has some other features in addition that allow to e.g. show a kernel density estimate.

#### Discrete variable

For a discrete variable, a histogram may or may not be suitable. If you use a `numpy.histogram`, the bins would need to be exactly inbetween the expected discrete observations.

```
x1 = np.random.randint(1,11,100)

hist, edges = np.histogram(x1, bins=np.arange(1,12)-0.5)
plt.bar(edges[:-1], hist, align="edge", ec="k", width=np.diff(edges))
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,11))
```

[image]

One could instead also count the unique elements in `x`,

```
u, counts = np.unique(x1, return_counts=True)
plt.bar(u, counts, align="center", ec="k", width=1)
plt.xticks(u)
```

resulting in the same plot as above. The main difference is for the case where not every possible observation is occupied. Say `5` is not even part of your data. A histogram approach would still show it, while it's not part of the unique elements.

```
x2 = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10], size=100)

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.title("histogram")
hist, edges = np.histogram(x2, bins=np.arange(1,12)-0.5)
plt.bar(edges[:-1], hist, align="edge", ec="k", width=np.diff(edges))
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,11))

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.title("counts")
u, counts = np.unique(x2, return_counts=True)
plt.bar(u.astype(str), counts, align="center", ec="k", width=1)
```

[image]

The latter is what `seaborn.countplot` does.

```
sns.countplot(x2, color="C0")
```

[image]

It is hence suitable for discrete or categorical variables.

#### Summary

All functions `pyplot.hist`, `seaborn.countplot` and `seaborn.displot` act as wrappers for a matplotlib bar plot and may be used if manually plotting such bar plot is considered too cumbersome.
For continuous variables, a `pyplot.hist` or `seaborn.distplot` may be used. For discrete variables, a `seaborn.countplot` is more convenient.

<sup>1. Note [`sns.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is deprecated since seaborn 0.11.2. For figure-level plots, use [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), and for axes-level plots, use [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot).</sup>

Comment: Actually, I think both continuous and discrete variables, hence numerical variables, should be presented with `pyplot.hist` or `seaborn.displot`, and `seaborn.countplot` should be used for categorical variables. From the seaborn documentation of `seaborn.countplot`:

*"Show the counts of observations in each categorical bin using bars... A count plot can be thought of as a histogram across a categorical, instead of quantitative, variable"*.

See https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html.

Comment: What's the difference between figure-level plots and axis-level plots