# TypeError: distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x' (or 'hue')

Tags: data-visualization, seaborn

I get the error when I try and plot this-

```
sns.distplot(X_train, x='Age')                   #Age is a feature in X_train
```

I get a similar error when I try and add the `hue` parameter in there

```
sns.distplot(X_train['Age'], hue=y_train)

TypeError: distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hue'
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Here is where I am trying out the code from-

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html

Comment: `displot` (no `t`) — and *not* `distplot` — is used in the link. I *suspect it’s a typo* with a method that is unfortunately named very similarly.

Comment: (If so, consider closing *or* self-voting-to-close as a typo.)

Comment: `sns.distplot(X_train, x='Age', data=X_train)`. The first parameter only sets the numerical data to use. The `data=...` tells which dataframe to use.  See also [what is major difference between histogram,countplot and distplot in Seaborn library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304913/what-is-major-difference-between-histogram-countplot-and-distplot-in-seaborn-lib) about similarly named functions.

Comment: FWIW, `disTplot` is deprecated.

Comment: @user2864740 Could you add that as an answer just in case someone else comes across the same issue? Also, turns out kaggle is using seaborn 0.10.0 and hence, does not recognise `displot`

Comment: I agree, it seems that `distplot` used to use `histplot` and `displot` as the main implementation, while the `distplot` method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If someone comes across this same issue, here's what lead to the confusion. Thanks @user2864740

`sns.distplot()` is deprecated.

`sns.displot()` is the new function with `hue` and `x` parameters.

If you get this error, update your seaborn version. In cmd -

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

From inside a notebook, add an ! before pip